# In Power Automation how do I enable email to add all people from 'Assign To' column in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, flow, tasks, power-automate

I created a flow 'when item is created or modified' to send email to user who is listed in the 'Assign To' column in SharePoint. The flow worked fine until my manager asked me to make the 'Assign To' column in SharePoint multi-select. So I updated it. Now my flow does not work.

How can I set my flow to send email to all persons listed in the 'Assign To' column in SharePoint?

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Initialize a blank string variable
2. Append the variable with the "Assigned To Email" field. This should add it into a new "Apply to Each" action.
3. After the new Apply to Each action, add the variable to the "To" field of your "Send an email from a shared mailbox action.

[image]

Comment: this did not work for me. The answer above worked for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.Add "**When an item is created or modified**" trigger

2.Add "**Initialize variable**" action

- Name: **AssignedToUsers**
- Type: **String**

3.Add "**Append to string variable**" action

- Name: **AssignedToUsers**
- Value:**Assign To Email;**

4.Add "Send an email(V2)" action

- To: **AssignedToUsers**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am getting an error.  Here's the error: **ExpressionEvalualtionFailed.** The execution of template action 'Apply_to_each_2 failed the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@triggerOutputs()?(body/AssignedTo']' is of type 'Object'. The result must be a valid array.

Comment: Hi Aleshia Thompson. "Apply to each 2" error? Can you tell me your whole flow process? This can help us solve the problem better.

Comment: After more searching, I found that I had to add the 'Compose' action to compose the output and return the json code. I added this to what you provided and it worked. Thanks so much for putting this in plain language. I appreciate that.